INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU. using typescript
i am creating a face detector app using google mediapipe and typescript. i am continuous getting this warning
:INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU."
while enable my camera
const predictWebcam = async () => {
if (!faceDetector) {
 console.error("FaceDetector is not initialized yet.");
 return;
 } else if (videoRef.current) {
  try {
  const detectionsResult = faceDetector.detectForVideo(
  videoRef.current,
  performance.now()
   );
    setDetections(detectionsResult.detections as Detection[]);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during detection:", error);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(predictWebcam);
  }

 };

give me solution for this

I recommend adding some more tags to your question, including tensorflow. More information about how you're creating faceDetector would also probably be helpful.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
